# How do I use angular-ui-router to insert a parameter into a template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the `id` parameter to my template. Here it the code I have so far:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('users', {
        url: "/user/:id/view",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "partials/users/nav.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

I need to insert the `id` parameter into the `partials/users/nav.html` template. How do I do this?

Comment: Check out this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T10gr1Leq6g basically I believe you would want to setup a controller as in the video and then setup your binding to the scope in the controller.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
     return 'partials/users/nav.html?id=' + $stateParams.id;
}
```